# Where does this NullReferenceException come from

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

here are some pretty simple lines of code, that throw a `NullReferenceException`. Since I get the exception via CloudDiagnostics I don't know which line threw the exception, but only which method.

```
private void DestroyChest() {
    if (Chest != null && Chest.gameObject == null) {
        Debug.LogException(new Exception("Chest.Gameobject is null!"));
    }

    Destroy(Chest?.gameObject);
}
```

`Chest` is a `MonoBehavior` script. And nowhere is a property accessed without checking it first.

Now my question is. Why and how do I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: My guess: `Destroy` doesn't like `null` values being passed to it.

Comment: @Llama no actually Unity doesn't like `Chest?` ;)

Comment: Rather use `if(Chest) Destroy(Chest.gameObject);` (see the duplicate link)

Comment: Destroy ignores `null` passed to it and unity is single threaded.

Comment: @derHugo please remove the association. If this would be the issue described in the associated post, i would get a `MissingReferenceException`. But since i get a `NullReferenceException` something else seems to be happening.

Comment: @T.Grumser no ... the `MissingReferenceException` only applies to the same frame right after `Destroy` where `Chest` is in that in-between state. Once the GarbageCollector does it's job the `Chest` will be `null` and you would get a `NullReferenceException` using `Chest?.gameObject` ... as said use `if(Chest) Destroy(Chest.gameObject);` and you should be fine in the future

Comment: Why would i get a null refference exception when Chest is `null` and i use the ?-operator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239536/discussion-between-t-grumser-and-derhugo).

Comment: I can't tell you the why exactly ... can't you just believe me and **never** use null checks and even less null conditionals/coalescings but rather simply the mentioned `bool` operator for just anything that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`? ;)

Comment: Ok actually I now remember why this happens: While `if(Chest != null)` uses the custom implementation of Unity for `UnityEngine.Object` `!=` and `Equals` the null conditional operator `?.` works only on the underlying `object` (Systm.Objetc) => They behave differently and since as mentioned in the dup it is **not really** `null` if you look at the `System.Object` .. it just returns `true` for `== null` since they overwrite this operator for `UnityEngine.Object`

Comment: @derHugo, everything you said is true, but would suggest, that i would receive a `MissingReferenceException`. But that is not the case. As stated in the question, the exceptions we're obtained from the CloudDiagnostics. And after buidling a non debugable build unity throws `NullReferenceException`s instead of `MissingReferenceException`s. And this is the answer to my question! I asked why i got a `NullRefereceException`, which i know now. Could you reopen the question so i can link your answer and explain, that this behind the scenes is a `MissingReferenceException`, that isn't shown correctly

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but could it be that your `if (Chest != null && Chest.gameObject == null) ` statement is throwing an exception because its not passing the second check? If `Chest` is actually null then it would pass the first check but since you're trying to grab the `gameObject` component of an object that doesn't exist it throws a  `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @A-Fairooz, this cannot be the case, since the second statement (`Chest.gameObject == null`) will not be evauated, if the first statement (`Chest != null`) is already false, which would be the case if `Chest` was `null`.